# How can i solve the error of node-red at start with new install

Tags: node-red

I've installed node-red from npm (but same result with snap) and as soon as i run node-red i have this error:

```
root@debian:/home/ipergola# node-red
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/runtime/lib/flows/Flow.js:797
    if (sendEvent?.destination?.node) {
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/runtime/lib/flows/index.js:19:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I'm notreally an expert of node-red, all help is wellcome.....

Answer (score 0):

The error implies you are using a version of NodeJS that doesn't support the `?.` syntax.

You've not said what version of Node-RED you have installed, but I suspect it's 3.1.0 as that is the latest. The minimum supported NodeJS version is 14, but since NodeJS 16 is already out of support you should really not be installing anything new on less than NodeJS 18.

p.s. you probably shouldn't be running Node-RED as root (unless you really know what you are doing and why)